# Operators in c++ chrono

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, c++-chrono

What are these operators in C++ chrono : `s` `10s` , `ns 10ns` , `ms 10 ms` , `h 10h`, `min 10 min`  I know that in `10s` means 10 seconds, `ms` means milliseconds, and so on.

Can I use letters as operators, or can I overload them?

Comment: ms means milliseconds, ns means nanoseconds...

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Comment: @Rakete1111 I said that

Comment: No, you didn't: `ns means milliseconds`

Comment: @NeilButterworth you can post this an answer , it was useful

Comment: I can post it without your permission, but I won't as links are not answers.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Ah it was typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [User Defined Literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal). Yes, you can define your own.

In a product I work on, we have defined several literals. For example, one is named `_qs` for `QString` literals, so we can write `"meow"_qs` and that is then a `QString` object - so we can do, for example:

```
const int num_cats = 42;
const auto foo = "we have %1 cats"_qs.arg(num_cats);
```

and `foo` will be a `QString` containing the text `"we have 42 cats"`. Quite handy.

Note that only the implementation can define names that do not start with underscore (`_`). All your own literals *must* start with `_`.

Comment: Literal suffix identifiers that do not start with an underscore are reserved for future standardization.